# jquery outerheight() for mobile/tablet on chrome returns 0

Tags: jquery, html, outerheight

I am trying to grab outerheight of a table data element, and I get the correct value on desktop, but mobile and tablet on chrome developer tools return 0.
JS:

```
var textRow = $('#table-data-row span');
console.log($(textRow).outerHeight(true));
```

HTML:

```
 <td><div id="table-data-row"><span>this is a test text right here</span></div></td>
```

Is there any solution for mobile browsers?

Comment: We need to see the html or the function that create the html if its dynamic. and also the css. so can see whats wrong.

Comment: @Alen.Toma i've added the html too.

Comment: I tested this and it work. you need to provide the whole thing so we could debug this further.

Comment: @Alen.Toma where did you run it? because I still get 0 for mobile/desktop

Comment: Chrome developer tools

Comment: @Alen.Toma ok, could it be because I have two different html with the same id? I am using the same id for mobile and desktop view. it works on desktop but doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: it is possible to have the same id.  but your problem is somthing else. this kind of problem usually be with css. look at the css of the span and also the td.

Comment: I disagree with the previous comment. An id must be unique, use a class instead.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the reason i used id is because i have a list of td.

Comment: When jQuery looks up for an id, the first hit is returned. The others are ignored. So it may work on desktop because the first hit is displayed... But hidden on mobile, making the outerHeight at zero.